# AWS - point my zone apex (mydomain.com versus www.mydomain.com) to Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm having trouble setting up an Route53 Apex Zone that point to an ELB and works on www and non-www domain names.

The domain name is datingjapan.co

In Route53 I have

- clicked new record set
- added the name www (I read to leave this blank but found the DNS lookup failed for www.datingjapan.co).
- clicked Alias and then in the Target I could select the ELB from the drop down.

ELB - I can see my 2 webservers are there and alive.

In apache httpd.conf I'm running a number of other sites (without ELB successfully - this is just temp until I get ELB working).

httpd.conf virtual site for datingjapan.co is

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/datingjapan.co
     ServerName datingjapan.co
     ServerAlias www.datingjapan.co
 </VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone advise what I might be doing wrong?

thankyou

Note: currently I can get to the site using www.datingjapan.co but not using datingjapan.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> added the name www (I read to leave this blank but found the DNS lookup failed for www.datingjapan.co).

While for most sites they point at the exact same thing, www.example.com and example.com are technically entirely separate records. You need a record for both www and non-www. Create another `ALIAS` record with the subdomain blank you'll be good to go.

Comment: ok I've add a record for both now - the root datingjapan.co is aliased to the EBL address and the www.datingjapan.co is aliased to datingjapan.co. Is this ok?

Comment: or should they both be aliased to the ELB address? Also I'm finding the www arrives at the site but the non-www doesn't - could this be to do with my VirtualHost config? thx

Comment: That should be fine. You could alternatively alias both of them to the ELB instead of using a CNAME for the www.

Comment: As for non-www not working, it's likely that you'll have to wait a while (depending on your TTL) as DNS records are cached for a while.

Comment: thx - pointed both to the ELB and I'll wait a couple of hours to see how it goes... cheers

Comment: @Adam Seems to be working now.

Comment: @Adam I'm also seeing both work.